# Symfony: Enable routes only in custom condition

Tags: symfony, routes

I have my `routing.yml` file and inside it i define the the routing files of all the application's bundles.

```
test_route:
    resource: "@test/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /

test_route_2:
    resource: "@test_2/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /
```

What i want to achieve is to enable the previous routes only under a custom condition. I want to pass a function there so i can make some complicated checks.

I don't know is Symfony supports this, so any kind of help/idea is welcome.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you need to check?

Comment: Each of my bundles have an Boolean active field in the database. If the bundle is not active in the database i need to return a 404 exception.

Comment: Just using the Symfony Routing component won't help you as the route collection is built at compile time. Though using the [Symfony CMF Routing component](https://github.com/symfony-cmf/routing) may be of help here. It offers a `DynamicRouter` which is able to read routes from the database.

Comment: Why you don't do this check in the controller of your bundle?